# Security Warning message displayed on some pages

Tags: security

I am using Jboss application server.
I have implemented the whole website on ssl (https), the site is working fine on internet explorer browser but the site displays the below information on Mozilla/Konqueror browser but only on a particular page.

**Security Warning :
Although this page is encrypted, the information you hav enetered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party.
Are you sure you want to continue ?
continue     cancel**

Is it a Jboss feature ?

If the whole site is running on https then why only n a particular page this information dislays ?

What should I do to get rid of this problem ?

Please do help me !!!!!!!!!   My mailid is **[redacted]**

Thanks and regards,

AKhtar Bhat

Answer (score 3):

Check for images or other resources that are being requested from non-SSL locations.  This is usually the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Posting your E-mail address here is probably not the best idea, it is likely to be harvested by spammers (although Gmail does have a fairly effective spam filter). It is also extremely unlikely anyone is going to answer you in E-mail since that would defeat the purpose of Stack Overflow, which is probably why your question was voted down.

To resolve your problem, you must find the page that is presenting the dialog or message you are seeing, then view the source of the webpage. Ensure the action attribute of any `<form>` tags are either relative to the current server (i.e. - `action="/some/path/..."`) or are absolute but are directed to https (i.e. - `action="https://some_server/some/path/..."`).

If you are using any AJAX calls, you must also ensure they are using https.

It seems unlikely the message is a result of resources being sent to you insecurely. It seems much more likely the message is a result of a `<form>` tag with an incorrect `action` attribute or an insecure AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

Check the FORM tag for ACTION property.
The action should be an HTTPS URL (which it should be if relative but may not be if absolute.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find some information on ths page that should help you

http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/04/23/fixing-the-ie-8-warning-do-you-want-to-view-only-the-webpage-content-that-was-delivered-securely/